# Binary Cross Entropy from Keras takes logits not from the output of model

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I am doing binary classification using Keras from TensorFlow 2.0, dense net with binary cross entropy loss.

For debugging purpose I was trying to overfit my model first and found weird behavior: I got different results of loss whether I used sigmoid in last dense layer init or initialize this last layer without any activation and add sigmoid activation separately as next step of the model.

I cannot find where in tf/keras it is stated that if last layer of model is just sigmoid and `BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` loss will be computed without that sigmoid. Or if there is other explanation of the following results.

As far as I understand `BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` expects logits- in this case output of Dense layer without any activation. That's the first example printed by posted code. As there is no activation, and only neuron has only one weight=1 the prediction is the same as input, as well as loss.

In the second variant I used Dense layer without activation in constructor, however I added sigmoid activation as "separate layer" and set `BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False)` in this case BCE doesn't take logits but ("probabilities") computed by `sigmoid(logits)` as input. Output predicted by model (probability) is equal to 1, which makes sense. However I expected Keras to take that probability, change it back to logit and compute loss [source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3653). Due to computational imprecise ([tf source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L373)) I figured out that BCE cannot compute higher loss than 15.3332 from not logits but it does in this case.

Expected behavior shows up in the last case (print of the code) where activation is in init of Dense layer- loss is clipped to 15.3332, no matter how big the input/output is if it is above 16.

My assumption is that in the second case loss is calculated from logits which is output of Dense layer, but is not the output of the model.

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import sigmoid
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
import numpy as np


x_train = np.array([[10000]])
y_train = [0]

inp = Input(x_train.shape[1])
out = Dense(1, trainable=False, use_bias=False)(inp)
model = Model(inp, out)
model.get_layer('dense').set_weights([np.array([[1]])])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True))

print('\nFrom logits=True, no activation')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
print('Prediction:')
print(model.predict(x_train))


inp = Input(x_train.shape[1])
out = Dense(1, trainable=False, use_bias=False)(inp)
out = sigmoid(out)
model = Model(inp, out)
model.get_layer('dense_1').set_weights([np.array([[1]])])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False))

print('\nFrom logits=False, separate sigmoid')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
print('Prediction:')
print(model.predict(x_train))


inp = Input(x_train.shape[1])
out = Dense(1, trainable=False, use_bias=False, activation='sigmoid')(inp)
model = Model(inp, out)
model.get_layer('dense_2').set_weights([np.array([[1]])])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False))

print('\nFrom logits=False, sigmoid in dense')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
print('Prediction:')
print(model.predict(x_train))
```

```
From logits=True, no activation
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/sample - loss: 1000.0000
Prediction:
[[1000.]]

From logits=False, separate sigmoid
Train on 1 samples
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/sample - loss: 1000.0000
Prediction:
[[1.]]

From logits=False, sigmoid in dense
Train on 1 samples
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/sample - loss: 15.3332
Prediction:
[[1.]]
```

Comment: Tensorflow 1.14 is consistent in that matter, I have posted this issue also on [tf git](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31930)

Comment: Unable to reproduce in TF 2.0

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/gist/jacekblaz/1b860965969dca734a7618c2009bf018/untitled.ipynb @rvinas